# Extending LDA model using Mallet

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I am trying to extend LDA model by adding another layer of locations.
Is it possible to add another layer to Mallet? if so, which classes should I extend?

The process I'm trying to model:
1. Choose a region
2. Choose a topic
3. Choose a word

Answer (score 3):

The `cc.mallet.topics.SimpleLDA` class is intended for use as a base for development of new models: https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/topics/SimpleLDA.java

There may be alternatives to designing a new model from scratch. If region completely determines the distribution over topics and each document comes from one region, you could simply merge all documents from a region. If each document has one or more regions, you could consider regions as "authors" and implement the Author-Topic model. If you want to measure a more indirect relationship between regions and topics you might try a Dirichlet-Multinomial Regression (DMR) model.